# How to get token from service account?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm new to Kubernetes. I need to get token from service account which was created by me. I used `kubectl get secrets` command and I got ***"No resources found in default namespace."*** as return. Then I used `kubectl describe serviceaccount deploy-bot-account` command to check my service account. It returns me as below.

```
Name:                deploy-bot-account
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the status of pods in kube-system namespace ?

Comment: @P.... pod status is Running

Comment: Are you using Kubernetes 1.24?  It no longer automatically creates a Secret; also see your newer question [Service account secret is not listed. How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256006/service-account-secret-is-not-listed-how-to-fix-it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service account secret is not listed. How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256006/service-account-secret-is-not-listed-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: @P.... Yeah it answered my question.

Comment: Consider marking this one as dupe.

Answer (score 0):

When service account is crated, k8s automatically creates a secrets and maps the same to sa. The secret contains ca.crt, token and namespace that are required for authN against API server.

refer the following commands

```
# kubectl create serviceaccount sa1


# kubectl get serviceaccount sa1 -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa1
  namespace: default
secrets:
- name: sa1-token-l2hgs



You can retrieve the token from the secret mapped to the service account as shown below

# kubectl get secret sa1-token-l2hgs -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ca.crt: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUN5RENDQWJDZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBREFWTVJNd0VRWURWUVFERXdwcmRXSmwKY201bGRHVnpNQjRYRFRJd01EUXlNakV4TVRVeE1Wb1hEVE13TURReU1ERXhNVFV4TVZvd0ZURVRNQkVHQTFVRQpBeE1LYTNWaVpYSnVaWFJsY3pDQ0FTSXdEUVlKS29aSWh2Y05BUUVCQlFBRGdnRVBBRENDQVFvQ2dnRUJBT2lCCk5RTVFPU0Rvdm5IcHQ2MjhkMDZsZ1FJRmpWbGhBb3Q2Uk1TdFFFQ3c3bFdLRnNPUkY4aU1JUDkrdjlJeHFBUEkKNWMrTXkvamNuRWJzMTlUaWEz-NnA0L0pBT25wNm1aSVgrUG1tYU9hS3gzcm13bFZDZHNVQURsdWJHdENhWVNpMQpGMmpBUXRCMkZrTUN2amRqNUdnNnhCTXMrcXU2eDNLQmhKNzl3MEFxNzZFVTBoTkcvS2pCOEd5aVk4b3ZKNStzCmI2LzcwYU53TE54TVU3UjZhV1d2OVJhUmdXYlVPY2RxcWk4WnZtcTZzWGZFTEZqSUZ5SS9GeHd6SWVBalNwRjEKc0xsM1dHVXZONkxhNThUdFhrNVFhVmZKc1JDUGF0ZjZVRzRwRVJDQlBZdUx-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
  namespace: ZGVmYXVsdA==
  token: ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpTVXpJMU5pSXNJbXRwWkNJNklpSjkuZXlKcGMzTWlPaUpyZFdKbGNtNWxkR1Z6TDNObGNuWnBZMlZoWTJOdmRXNTBJaXdpYTNWaVpYSnVaW-FJsY3k1cGJ5OXpaWEoyYVdObFlXTmpiM1Z1ZEM5dVlXMWxjM0JoWTJVaU9pSmtaV1poZFd4MElpd2lhM1ZpWlhKdVpYUmxjeTVwYnk5elpYSjJhV05sWVdOamIzVnVkQzl6WldOeVpYUXVibUZ0WlNJNkluTmhNUzEwYjJ0bGJpMXNNbWhuY3lJc0ltdDFZbVZ5Ym1WMFpYTXVhVzh2YzJWeWRtbGpaV0ZqWTI5MWJuUXZjMlZ5ZG1salpTMWhZMk52ZFc1MExtNWhiV1VpT2lKellURWlMQ0pyZFdKbGNtNWxkR1Z6TG1sdkwzTmxjblpwWTJWaFkyTnZkVzUwTDNObGNuWnBZMlV0WVdOamIzVnVkQzUxYVdRaU9pSXhaRFUyWW1Vd09DMDRORGt4TFRFeFpXRXRPV0ppWWkwd01qUXlZV014TVRBd01UVWlMQ0p6ZFdJaU9pSnplWE4wWlcwNmMyVnlkbWxqWldGalkyOT-FiblE2WkdWbVlYVnNkRHB6WVRFaWZRLmFtdGFORHZUNE9DUlJjZVNpTUE0WjhxaExIeTVOMUlfSG12cTBPWDdvV3RVNzdEWl9wMnVTVm13Wnlqdm1DVFB0T01acUhKZ29BX0puYUphWmlIU3IyaGh3Y2pTN2VPX3dhMF8tamk0ZXFfa0wxVzVNMDVFSG1YZFlTNzdib-DAtZ29jTldxT2RORVhpX1VBRWZLR0RwMU1LeFpFdlBjamRkdDRGWVlBSmJ5LWRqdXNhRjhfTkJEclhJVUNnTzNLUUlMeHZtZjZPY2VDeXYwR3l4ajR4SWRPRTRSSzZabzlzSW5qY0lWTmRvVm85Y3o5UzlvaGExNXdrMWl2VDgwRnBqU3dnUUQ0OTFqdEljdFppUkJBQzIxZkhYMU5scENaQTdIb3Zvck5Yem9maGpmUG03V0xRUUYyQjc4ZkktUEhqMHM2RnNpMmI0NUpzZzFJTTdXWU50UQ==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: sa1
    kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 1d56be08-8491-11ea-9bbb-0242ac110015
  name: sa1-token-l2hgs
  namespace: default
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Comment: In my case, secrets is not created. I used `kubectl get serviceaccount sa1 -oyaml` command and return as 
`apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-16T06:53:37Z"
  name: cart-function
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "14353"
  uid: 9dbaf92e-ea4a-4e8a-b0df-165d9c4f3499` only

Comment: follow the link shared by david https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256006/service-account-secret-is-not-listed-how-to-fix-it

Comment: It appears like from1.24 version service account secret is not automatically generated. it should be manually created.

Answer (score 0):

Use below format to create the Secret for your serviceaccount

After the Secret is created, a Kubernetes controller fills in some other fields such as the kubernetes.io/service-account.uid annotation, and the token key in the data field, which is populated with an authentication token. you can decode the base64 token and use it where you want in like your CICD pipeline user creation in my case.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-sa-sample
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "sa-name"
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
data:
  extra: YmFyCg==
```