# AWS: Assume an IAM Role using a Web Identity Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster with an OpenID Connect provider. My goal is to configure cross-account permissions to allow Pods running on the cluster in Account A to access AWS resources in Account B. To achieve this I have created a Service Account and attached that to the relevant Pods in Account A.

My issue is that before I can get the change approved, I need to prove that it works.

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cross-account-access.html) seems to suggest that I can test the use of `STS:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` via the CLI. However, where it specifies `web_identity_token_file`, it doesn't actually tell you how to generate that token.

Magic Google led me to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251976/how-to-get-token-from-service-account), and now I have created a secret for the Service Account in question and I can get a JWT token. However, when I use that token I see an error -

> operation error STS: AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, InvalidIdentityToken: Issuer must be a valid URL

The above SO question then led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76359185/567059) in another question, but generating a token this way leads to another error.

> operation error STS: AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, InvalidIdentityToken: Incorrect token audience

So my question is, how can I test assumption of a role with a web identity through the CLI? Is there a way to generate a generic JWT token for the OIDC provider for my EKS cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is to use `kubectl create token` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76359185/567059), but in addition to that it is necessary to change the audience, as the default audience is not valid.

```bash
kubectl create token <sa> -n <namespace> --audience sts.amazonaws.com
```

Note that no Service Account linked Secret is required.